# How to convert special characters to html words through PHP?

Tags: php, html, decode

I have so many special characters like this in mysql data while I am displaying in xml file through php.

```
&mdash;,&rdquo;,&rsquo;,&ldquo;...etc
```

I want to convert as a original words using php.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for [**html_entity_decode**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php)

Comment: after using that tag i got xml error..that is                               error on line 5 at column 859: xmlParseEntityRef: no name

Answer (score 0):

```
$s = ' &mdash;,&rdquo;,&rsquo;,&ldquo;';
echo html_entity_decode($s);
```

All you need is http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php

Comment: after using that tag i got xml error..that is error on line 5 at column 859: xmlParseEntityRef: no name

Answer (score -1):

You should go with [`htmlspecialchars_decode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php) as `html_entity_decode` is a ***slighter - overkill version***.

```
<?php
$s = '&mdash;,&rdquo;,&rsquo;,&ldquo;';
echo htmlspecialchars_decode($s);
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
—,”,’,“
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
$orig = "I'll \"walk\" the <b>dog</b> now";
```

> `$a = htmlentities($orig);`

```
  echo $a; // I'll &quot;walk&quot; the &lt;b&gt;dog&lt;/b&gt; now
```

> `$b = html_entity_decode($a);`

```
  echo $b; // I'll "walk" the <b>dog</b> now
?>
```

Comment: after using that tag i got xml error..that is error on line 5 at column 859: xmlParseEntityRef: no name